# Payment Structure for Non-Voting LLC Member

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, oregon

I'm dealing with a member-managed LLC that has both members and employees. The LLC wishes to bring in another member. The Operating Agreement provides that the shares for the new member will not confer voting rights for X months, but does provide profit/loss sharing and everything else. After X months, it converts to a regular class of membership.

My question is: will this situation influence how this new member is taxed? The expectation is that it will be taxed as a pass-through of an active member (ie, nothing withheld), but I can't find any confirmation of this.

State is Oregon, if it matters.